# verb-with-preposition and verb-with-other-preposition

Tags: grammar, commas, phrasal-verbs

*Abstruse algorithms have been derived for, and implemented in, superfluous software* --- correct? readable? better with or without commas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine in a sentence two verb–preposition pairs that have the same object?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/how-to-combine-in-a-sentence-two-verb-preposition-pairs-that-have-the-same-objec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct and works both with and without the commas. The use of commas would slightly alter the meaning by conveying that 'implemented in' is mentioned in passing, but not of equal importance to 'derived for'.

About verbs sharing an object, see also:

- [How to combine in a sentence two verb-preposition pairs that have the same object?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/how-to-combine-in-a-sentence-two-verb-preposition-pairs-that-have-the-same-objec)

  - [Comma usage with one subject, multiple verbs, and multiple objects](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/318958/comma-usage-with-one-subject-multiple-verbs-and-multiple-objects)

About comma usage for parentheses (or bracketing comma), see also:

- [parentheses vs double commas vs dashes to provide additional detail](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4522/parentheses-vs-double-commas-vs-dashes-to-provide-additional-detail/4530#4530)
- [which type of comma is used here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95328/which-type-of-comma-is-used-here)

Comment: Hello, ATJ. Well done on finding previous answers, but the idea is to have a single and thus (hopefully) easily searchable database of answers on English Usage, not to provide answers to every repeat of a question. We close-vote on 'duplicate' grounds.

Comment: @Edwin - fair enough. I admit I would have just posted this as a comment to the OP, but I don't have high enough privileges to do that yet. Would you recommend taking down my answer?

Comment: No; the comment above will hopefully decourager les autres. // As an aside, a reasonable candidate for a parenthetical with zero punctuation.